# Rape e cime di rapa

Tags: single-words

Questo post è simile al mio post a riguardo di bietole e barbabietole, che pur riferendosi a piante diverse hanno nomi simili, come se ci fosse qualche legame tra le due piante, di un tipo o di un alto.

Vorrei chiedere, se le cime di rapa sono una pianta diversa dalla pianta che ha la rapa come tubero, allora perché si chiamano cime di rapa, come se fossero la parte superiore della rapa la quale ha un tubetto di sotto.

Grazie.

Comment: tubetto = tubero?

Comment: Cima nel senso di "parte superiore" ossia quello che sta  sopra la rapa (le foglie).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

***[Rapa:](http://dizionari.corriere.it/dizionario_italiano/R/rapa.shtml)*** da il Sabatini Coletti:

> - Pianta erbacea coltivata, con piccoli fiori dorati, foglie che vengono utilizzate come foraggio e grossa radice carnosa commestibile; *estensione nel linguaggio comune*, la radice della pianta: *un chilo di rape*.

[image]

> - ***cime di rapa***, foglie giovani e infiorescenze commestibili della rapa.

[image]

Comment: Dunque la rapa e le cime di rapa provengono dalla stessa pianta. Grazie.